# Acrobat fill and email PDF

Tags: pdf, acrobat

We have an Acrobat PDF. It has a "button" where after filling you hover over it and it sends the filled document via your default email client.

I'm opening the document in Acrobat Pro DC and I can find absolutely no way to find out how this is set to do this.

Can anyone help out on this?

Comment: What does the creator say in the Document Info? (is somewhere "Livecycle" involved? (and a general rant… using a hover action to send files is very bad practice).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Acrobat, from The 'Tools' bar, open 'Forms', and select 'Edit'.
Find the button on the page, right-click on it and select 'Properties' from the context menu. Switch to the 'Actions' tab.

The 'Trigger' might possibly be 'On Focus', though 'Mouse Up' is more conventional, and the 'Action' is likely to be a JavaScript action which calls fdf.mail(), see the Acrobat DC JavaScript API Reference for more info.

Alternatively, consider the 'Submit a Form' action.